# dcc32 Fatal Error F2084 Internal Error: AV116B241E(11640000)-R00000378-0

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi (Version 28.0.42600.6491).

Often (about two times per day) when i'm working, i get this error when trying to compiling any project. Only workaround is to close the IDE and open it again :

dcc32 Fatal Error F2084 Internal Error: AV116B241E(11640000)-R00000378-0

It's not a big deal but this happens everyday.

Any hints to fix it for good ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try and find a way to reliably reproduce it. Usually it is some odd/new/etc code construct which makes it very hard to track down until some source reliably triggers it.  It is a very generic error unfortunately, an example of an older case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153388.

Comment: Submit a bug report to the product vendor

Comment: I know this annoying problem too.  Its occurrence is always associated with generic methods. What annoys me more is that I can no longer debug via a project group. Breakpoints in the other project always show the CPU window without reference to the source code. Breakpoints work in the project I'm starting from. I work with Delphi Sydney.

Comment: @Brian Can't reproduce, there is no pattern , sometimes it won't happen all day long, other times will happen twice a day

Answer (score 1):

it uses to happen alto to me... i have no ideia what can lead to this ERROR but in my case i found that it was triggered on a function where i was comparing to TObject members of a class

IE: Self.Parent=NewComponent.Parent

my solution was to find a work arround to eleminate the Object comparison and use other datatype reference for comparison

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal compiler error. Embarcadero recommends that as soon as you see it, you should restore your code to the previous working state and rewrite it so that the internal compiler error is not triggered.

The nasty thing is that this kind of error does not appear in small projects and even in large project it does not appear always.

I have two large projects where the error appears pretty consistently. However, Emba wants me to send all my code to them (million-range LOC) so they can fix it. Obviously, this cannot happen.

Maybe one day, they will learn to use a tool like MadShi MadExcept (great tool!) to see what is really happening inside the compiler.

---

PS: The error msg says that you need to restart the IDE but I have seen that in 95% of the cases, it is not necessary. A Build (build, not compile) command is enough. The problem is that the compilation takes 16 seconds while the build takes 1.5 minutes.